# Node.js fs.unlinkSync removes files but not folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, fs

I can remove all image files (.png, .jpg, etc...), but I can't remove folders...

This is my code blog:

```
router.post('/remove-file', async (req, res) => {

    const removeDocuments = await req.body.removeDocuments
    // removeDocuments[0] equals to '/assets/img/folder'
    // removeDocuments[1] equals to '/assets/img/image.jpg'

    if(removeDocuments){

        for (let i = 0; i < removeDocuments.length; i++) {
            fs.unlinkSync('.' + removeDocuments[i])
        }

        res.send({
            status: true
        })

    }

})
```

The error code I get:

```
(node:808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink './assets/img/folder'
```

Where is the problem I did? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlink removes a name from the filesystem, and the file it referenced. It doesn't remove directories, as that could create orphan files. Use [rmSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmsync_path_options) with `recursive: true` to delete directories.

Comment: That's works, thanks. Also `rmdirSync` is works without using `recursive: true`.
But only removes folders which is empty!!!